# Attack on a person resting in a parked car

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a French film on British TV some years ago, probably released in the period 1999-2007, the name and most details of which I cannot remember. I *think* it was shown as part of a series of French films, maybe including [*Harry, He's Here to Help*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry,_He%27s_Here_to_Help), but I'm unsure.

It featured:

- Some tranquil scenes at an outdoor swimming pool, possibly at a holiday camp, earlier in the film.
- A surprise attack on a person sleeping/resting in a parked car, towards the end of the film.

The latter was extremely shocking, even after earlier scenes had created an unsettling tone. The car was parked in a car park after dark, I think at a motorway/highway service/gas station. It seemed like a quiet place. All of a sudden, an assailant was smashing through the windscreen, possibly with a pickaxe or hammer or suchlike - I don't remember exactly.

I seem to recall that the film had been on general release in the cinema for a while, before being shown on TV, and had had middling to good reviews. I think it was at least partly funded by a French arts council of some kind.

I have a vague idea that the plot arc concerned a coming-of-age story against a backdrop of family trouble, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swimming pool and the attack at the end sound like Catherine Breillat's [Fat Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Girl), (2001).

> On the way back she becomes tired and decides to sleep at a rest stop,
>   where an axe murderer arrives, killing Elena with an axe and
>   strangling her mother.